# How to keep AI goalkeeper inside their bounds

Tags: unity, c#, game-mechanics, transformation

I'm making a soccer-themed top-down 2D endless game, but I have a problem with the goalkeeper AI.

My game looks like this:

[image: Game animation]

As you can see, the goalKeeper is moving out of bounds.

I have tried to clamp them with

```
transform.Translate(Mathf.Clamp(target.transform.position.x,-1,1),0,0)
```

...but I think this for clamping the speed, not the area boundaries. What should I do instead?

[image]

What I want is to have two kinds of goalkeeper:

- **Active Goalkeeper** (Call them `GKA`)

  This goalkeeper should chase the player, but only within the bounds of the goal area.
- **Stationary Goalkeeper** (Call them just `GK`)

  This goalkeeper should just stand in the middle of the goal, like in the first animation. But before the player reaches them I want this goal keeper to move forward slightly, to pretend it's defending the goal.

[image]

Here is my goalkeeper script:

```
if (gameObject.CompareTag("GK"))
    {
        anim.SetBool("GKRun", false);
        gkballInRange = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(transform.position, gkballRange, playerMask);
        float distancePlayer = Vector2.Distance(target.position, transform.position);

        if (gkballInRange)
        {
            transform.Translate(0, -.3f * Time.deltaTime, 0);
            if (distancePlayer <= gkballRange)
            {
                if (theBall.isOver)
                {
                    anim.SetBool("GkC", true);
                    anim.SetBool("GKRun", false);
                    transform.Translate(0, 0, 0);
                }
                else
                {
                    //Animation
                    anim.SetBool("GKRun", true);
                    transform.Translate(target.transform.position.x * speed * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
                }
            }

        }

    }
```

and this one is GKA script:

```
if (gameObject.CompareTag("GKA"))
    {

        //Animation
        gkballInRange = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(transform.position, gkballRange, playerMask);
        float distancePlayer = Vector2.Distance(target.position, transform.position);

        if (gkballInRange)
        {
            transform.Translate((target.position.x * Time.deltaTime), 0, 0);

            if (distancePlayer <= gkballRange)
            {

                if (theBall.isOver)
                {
                    anim.SetBool("GkC", true);
                    anim.SetBool("GKRun", false);
                    transform.Translate(0, 0, 0);
                }
                else
                {
                    anim.SetBool("GKRun", true);
                    transform.Translate(0, -speed * Time.deltaTime, 0);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I've tried to edit this question for clarity — please feel free to revise it further if I misunderstood you. I'm not sure I understand the "little move forward" you described for the stationary goalkeeper `GK` — can you elaborate on how they should behave, or maybe show us a step-by-step diagram of what you want them to do?

Comment: Thank you for the advice and edit this question too ill add more information @DMGregory and I've updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After applying the goalkeeper's speed, you should Clamp the resulting position to make sure it's within bounds. Here's an example:

```
transform.Translate(speed,0,0);
transform.localPosition = new Vector3(
    Mathf.Clamp(transform.localPosition.x,-1,1),
    transform.localPosition.y,
    transform.localPosition.z);
```

This assumes only the X axis is to be clamped. It's also been a while since I've worked on  Unity, not sure if there is a better way than creating a new `Vector3` every frame, but the result should be correct.

Comment: where should I implement this?

Comment: @YouCanCallMeSyarif In the same place where you implement the goal keeper's speed, I assume somewhere inside `Update` ? For my example, assume `transform` refers to the goalkeeper's `Transform`.

Comment: I've tried with yours, but why the goalKeeper always stand on the right like the `X-axis != 0`

Comment: Your math clamp needs to take into consideration how big your actual goal is. You could place your gk to the left of the goal, note down the value, to the right, note down the value and adjust your math.clamp. If your goal keeper runs too much forward, you need to clamp y as well

Comment: @YouCanCallMeSyarif I'm not sure how your hierarchy is set up. The example code above will make sure the `transform` is always between `-1` and `1`. I'm not sure if in your case `0` is the center of the goal, or if each side extends by 1 unit. Play a bit with the numbers, until you get the desired result.

Comment: but how about the stationary one? move a little bit from wicket post @Zibelas like the picture.

Comment: @TomTsagk thank you that is my fault for put in the wrong line.

Comment: well, you can take the current position as his y start value and clamp it against how much he can run forward. You can save his original position when you instantiate the gk and it will be something like Mathf.Clamp(transform.localPosition.y, startingPos.y- maxRunningDistance, startingPos.y),

Comment: @Zibelas if you don't mind can you write it down one Answer, because I tried on `transform.translate(Mathf.Clamp(transform.localPosition.y, startingPos.y- maxRunningDistance, startingPos.y))` error the object too far from origin.

Answer (score 0):

An addition to the answer from TomTsagk.

You are using your current transform.translate as it is. This code is placed after the translate, if the gk is running out of the bounds, you are clipping his position back into the bounds. You achieve this with the Mathf.Clamp.

For the forward running, you treat it the same way as a sideway running.

```
transform.localPosition = new Vector3(
    Mathf.Clamp(transform.localPosition.x, -widthOfGoal/2, widthOfGoal/2),
    Mathf.Clamp(transform.localPosition.y, -maxForwardDistance, 0),
    transform.localPosition.z);
```

This assumes that your goalkeeper is placed at 0, 0, 0 at his localPosition.

Comment: thank you for the information you all help me a lot.